# Can't get UNET work between two Devices using the standard NetworkManager(NOT the MatchMaking!) on Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, lan, unity3d-unet

I am new to UNET UNITY NETWORKING in general so what I made was a simple prototype game  and everything works perfectly at least at that moment when I run two instances of the game on the same laptop so i was able to host and join form one instance to another

[image: take a look here]

so it did exactly what I expected but when used another laptop and connected to the same wifi
I couldn't join with the hosted device anymore, i also tried it on mobile but the same thing happened

this is what it says when i run the game on two devices

[image: this is what it says when i run the game on two devices]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to `localhost` (the devices local address). That obviously doesn't work for connecting to another device.

You have to configure the IP/Address of the device that will later actually be hosting the game in the [`NetworkManager`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetManager.html) component:

[image]

---

Alternatively I can recommend the

[`NetworkManagerHUD`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NetworkManagerHUD.html) component (has to be attached next to the `NetworkManager` component on the same GameObject)

so in the game you can still dynamically adjust the host IP/Address as shown in [Using the `NetworkManagerHUD`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetManagerHUD.html):

[image]

---

Or if you want to go crazy you can instead also use the [`NetworkDiscovery`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NetworkDiscovery.html) to auto-discover a host in your local network (LAN - doesn't work for internet connections).

Easiest mode simply make sure to enable `Use NetworkManager`

> Enable this to use the Network Manager
>   settings for broadcasting, and to then auto-join found games.

otherwise you can also implement your own script for handling the sending and receiving of broadcast messages.

---

#### UNet deprication

In general keep in mind that

> UNet is deprecated, and will be removed from Unity in the future. A new system is under development. For more information and next steps see [this blog](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/08/02/evolving-multiplayer-games-beyond-unet/) post and the [FAQ](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001252086-UNet-Deprecation-FAQ).